# Is sending USDT to Ethereum main network address Possible?

Tags: erc-20, ether, metamask, usdt

I copied my Metamask Ethereum main network Ethereum wallet address to someone who said "Supported Wallets: ERC-20 Compatible. E.g. Metamask," for payment. I want to know if the transaction will be successful. The person

Comment: yes. it will be successful

Comment: It seems like you got cut off halfway through writing your sentence, were you going to say anything else after "The person"?